# How do you override the ruby case equality operator? (===)

Tags: ruby, overloading

I have a class that I want to compare to both strings and symbols in a case statement, so I thought that I just override the ===() method for my class and all would be gold. However my ===() method never gets called during the case statement.  Any ideas?

Here is some example code, and what happens in a irb session:

```
class A
   def initialize(x)
      @x=x #note this isn't even required for this example
   end
   def ===(other)
      puts "in ==="
      return true
   end
end
```

> irb(main):010:0> a=A.new("hi")
>   => #  
>   irb(main):011:0> case a 
>   irb(main):012:1> when "hi" then 1 
>   irb(main):013:1> else 2 
>   irb(main):014:1> end
>   => 2

(it never prints the message and should always return true anyway)
Note that ideally I'd like to do a

```
def ===(other)
          #puts "in ==="
          return @x.===(other)
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression after the 'case' keyword is the right hand side of the === expression, and the expression after the 'when' keyword is on the left hand side of the expression.  So, the method that is being called is String.===, not A.===.

A quick approach to reversing the comparison:

```
class Revcomp
    def initialize(obj)
        @obj = obj
    end

    def ===(other)
        other === @obj
    end

    def self.rev(obj)
        Revcomp.new(obj)
    end
end

class Test
    def ===(other)
        puts "here"
    end
end

t = Test.new

case t
when Revcomp.rev("abc")
    puts "there"
else
    puts "somewhere"
end
```

Comment: Cool. That explains it, and it works! Does this way of doing case statements seem counter intuitive?

Comment: Good.  Yes, it does seem a bit messy, but I didn't give the syntax much thought for this answer.  You can probably come up with some more concise syntax, or you can do something evil like override operator=== in the classes you want to have on the LHS.

Comment: Thanks - I can be a bit more concise but it also makes me think I'm maybe using the wrong tool (case) for the job, but it does work, so thank you ( I should have asked this yesterday ).

Comment: No problem.  You could also do something simple like have a method on your class that returns the string you want to use in the comparison.  That way you avoid doing anything special with === at all.

Comment: It makes perfect sense: a.===(b) means "Hey, 'a', is 'b' a member of you?" It doesn't make sense for a Number to know whether it is a member of a Range, but a Range should know whether a Number is inside itself. So, it makes sense for '1..3 === 2' and 'case 2 when 1..3' to mean the same thing.

Comment: BTW: don't take "member" too literally. I always think about it like this: a === b means: if there were several bins, and one of the bins was labeled 'a', does it make sense to throw 'b' in there? So, for example Module#=== means the same thing as Object#kind_of? Because if you have a bin that is ..

Comment: ... labeled "String Class" and you have a String object, it makes sense to throw it in there, right?

Comment: @Jorg, I can see what you mean.. it's the container's job to know whether an object belongs to it.  And I can see that with ranges, but [1,2,3] === 2 yields false, so it's not a universally held convention, which is a shame.  But I understand this now, so that's cool.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Apparently, Array doesn't have an implementation of ===, therefore it inherits Object#===, which is the same as Object#== (equality). I agree, Array#=== should be a membership test.

Comment: For containers it's cool, but for user-defined classes that metaphor doesn't really hold as well, and reversing the comparison is the way to go.