# How to make a ruby case statement use equals to (==) rather than threequals (===)

Tags: ruby

Ruby's case statement uses `===` by default. Is there a way to make it use 'equals to' (i.e. `==`) instead?

The motivation for doing so is because I have 5 `if` statements that would very nicely be replaced by a switch, but I was a little surprised to learn that

```rb
datatype = "string".class
```

```rb
if datatype == String
puts "This will print"
end
```

is not the same as

```rb
case datatype
when String
puts "This will NOT print"
end
```

Comment: [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/629722/10522579) can you help for this.

Comment: Ruby's case statement uses `===`. It doesn't "use it **by default**".

Comment: I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694333/5783745) (looks like behaviour of `case` with respect to classes has tripped up some others too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot let `case` to not use `===`, but you can redefine `===` to use `==`.

```
class Class
  alias === ==
end

case datatype
when String
  puts "This will print"
end
# >> This will print
```

---

Alternatively, you can create a specific class for doing that.

```
class MetaClass
  def initialize klass
    @klass = klass
  end

  def ===instance
    instance == @klass
  end
end

def meta klass
  MetaClass.new(klass)
end

case datatype
when meta(String)
  puts "This will print"
end
# >> This will print
```

Comment: Is it dangerous to redefine `===` ? Could it be used in other methods (that I may not be aware of) and is it possible I might ruin disrupt other methods by redefining it?

Comment: `===` is rarely used other than in `case` statements, so it is not that dangerous. But if you have concerns with it interacting with other parts of the code, then consider changing the aliasing into a method definition within a Refinement and use the relevant `case` statement within the scope of the Refinement.

Comment: This is kind of same given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/629722/10522579) but nicely put here +1

Answer (score 3):

This would be a more concise and cleaner (IMSO) approach to what @sawa had suggested. Use λ instead of the wrapper class.

```
META = ->(type, receiver) { receiver == type }

case "string".class
when META.curry[Integer] then puts 'integer'  
when META.curry[String] then puts 'string'  
end  

#⇒ "string"
```

This solution uses [`Proc#curry`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-curry) and [`Proc#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Aleksei Matiushkin's answer, but without the curry:

```
is_class = ->(klass) { ->(item) { item == klass } }

10.times do
  case ['abc', 123].sample.class
  when is_class[String]
    puts "it's the abc"
  when is_class[Integer]
    puts "easy as 123"
  end
end
```

What happens here?

- The first line defines a proc that returns another proc
- `proc[x]` is the same as `proc.call(x)`
- `proc.===(x)` is the same as `proc.call(x)`
- `is_class[Integer]` returns a proc that does `{ |val| val == Integer }`
- ..which gets called by case with the case's parameter as argument because of `===` ==> `call`.

The big downside is it creates a lot of procs and looks weird.

Of course the obvious solution to your question would be to not do `datatype = "string".class`:

```
datatype = "string"
case datatype
when String
puts "This will print"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the explicit form of case statement

```
datatype = test_object.class

case
when datatype == String
  puts "It's a string"
when datatype < Numeric
  puts "It's a number"
end
```

Note that the expression *datatype < Numeric* will be true for all numeric types.